# rails custom error exception implementation is bloated, suggestions for drying it up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

In application_controller.rb there is a method to render 404 errors with a custom layout and partial.

**application_controller.rb:**

```
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError,       with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController,  with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction,      with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,         with: :render_404
  end
```

**This calls any of the methods:**

```
  def render_404(exception)
    notify exception
    @not_found_path = exception.message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/error_404', layout: 'layouts/error', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def render_500(exception)
    notify exception
    @error = exception
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/error_404', layout: 'layouts/error', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 500 }
    end
  end
```

**Then there is error_controller.rb:**

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  layout "error"

  def sub_layout
    "left"
  end

  def error_404
    @not_found_path = params[:not_found]
    render "errors/error_404"
  end

  def error_500
    render "errors/error_500"
  end

end
```

QUESTION:
This feels very bloated, Is there a way to have it render the custom error page now situated in /app/views/errors/error_404.html.haml ? with custom layout?

I want to delete my error_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default path for rendering 404 and 500 html responses is in the public folder.  I'd replace the default 404.html with your error_404.html

```
render :file => 'public/404.html', :layout => layouts/error
```

Comment: thanks but that is non dynamic static html ( no translations and other goodies, so not a real solution )